# How to allow the user to click on a link while displaying a photoswipe gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I am using the [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/documentation) Plugin for jQuery.

My website uses a fixed menu, when the user has scrolled down.

With a z-index I was not able to make the photoswipe gallery overlap my menu. So I resized the default pane of photoswipe, to spare out the space for the menu. This appearance I also prefer.

Now when I open a photo, but than navigate to an other page with PhotoSwipe, some callback of PhotoSwipe appears to redirect the user back to where he came from.

If I use the destroy call back of photoswip and put an alert in it, this delays the redirection (back to the page where the user came from).

How can I allow a user to close a photoswipe gallery, without being redirected?

**EDIT:**
This is how I initialize the photoswipe gallery.

```
function showSoftwareGallery(sections, index){
    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

    var items = new Array(sections.length);
    for(var i=0; i<sections.length; i++){
        items[i] = {
            src: sections[i].image,
            w: 1920,
            h: 1080,
        };
    }

// define options (if needed)
    var options = {
        // optionName: 'option value'
        // for example:
        index: index, // start at first slide
        escKey: true,
        arrowKeys: true,
        shareEl: false,
        closeEl:true,
        captionEl: true,
        fullscreenEl: true,
        zoomEl: true,
    };

// Initializes and opens PhotoSwipe
    var headerHeight = $('nav').first().height();
    var height = $(window).height() - headerHeight;
    $('.pswp').first().css('height', height + 'px');
    $('.pswp').first().css('top', headerHeight + 'px');
    var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);


    gallery.listen('destroy', function() { alert('destroy')});


    gallery.init();
}
```

**Edit 2**
You see here a screenshot of my photoswipe display. It shows that my main menu is still visible and the user can click on it.
[image]

Comment: Have you populated the items variable? Post your code initializing and calling photoswipe.

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Well those were issues I've had with photoswipe: improper items variable, javascript error (in that case image gets opened in that tab). What you might also have is issue that your menu gets clicked and takes user somewhere? Honestly I don't know what you mean by this: `Now when I open a photo, but than navigate to an other page with PhotoSwipe, some callback of PhotoSwipe appears to redirect the user back to where he came from.` How can you navigate to other page with photoswipe? Redirects user where? Where did the user come from?

Comment: I added a screenshot. Maybe you understand all now better. Here the scenary; 1.) user opens a photo with photoswipe. 2.) User clicks on a link in the menu 3.) photoswipe gallery closes 4.) meteor.js changes the location of the user and displays an other page 5.) a photoswipe callback redirects the user to the page he was at, at the beginning.

Comment: I just looked at their `photoswipe.js` which is I guess everything combined. You'll need to figure it out yourself, as a hint search for `'close'` and `'destroy'`. These are events that they fire. Especially search for `_listen('destroy', function()` because it has code that says: `if(!_hashReseted) { returnToOriginal(); }`
 and that sounds exactly like what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`src/js/history.js` file contains this code:

```
        _listen('destroy', function() {
            if(!_hashReseted) {
                returnToOriginal();
            }
        });
```

You didn't provide reproducible code, so this isn't 100%, but should be helpful. I'd change that code to this:

```
        _listen('destroy', function() {
            if(!_hashReseted && !myApp.shouldClosePhotoswipe) {
                returnToOriginal();
            }
        });
```

In your app add this code:

```
var myApp = {
    // mix in with your javascript code
    shouldClosePhotoswipe: false
}
```

And when menu is clicked to go somewhere just add this line:

```
myApp.shouldClosePhotoswipe = true;
```

Then you need to rebuild `dist/photoswipe.js` file.
You could also just edit the `dist/photoswipe.js` file directly.